# Retornar valor Ajax em input

Tags: php, ajax

Montei uma query usando php+oracle para buscar o nome do funcionário a partir do crachá. Pesquisei e encontrei um script que faz a consulta e retorna na mesma página usando Ajax. Mas ele retorna o valor somente na div inteira. Como faço para retornar em um campo que eu defino? Exemplo:

```js
 function getDados() {

 // Declaração de Variáveis
 var nome   = document.getElementById("txtnome").value;
 var result = document.getElementById("Resultado");
 var xmlreq = CriaRequest();

 // Exibi a imagem de progresso
 result.innerHTML = '<img src="images/Progresso.gif"/>';

 // Iniciar uma requisição
 xmlreq.open("GET", "processa.php?txtnome=" + nome, true);

 // Atribui uma função para ser executada sempre que houver uma mudança de ado
 xmlreq.onreadystatechange = function(){

     // Verifica se foi concluído com sucesso e a conexão fechada (readyState=4)
     if (xmlreq.readyState == 4) {

         // Verifica se o arquivo foi encontrado com sucesso
         if (xmlreq.status == 200) {
             result.innerHTML = xmlreq.responseText;
         }else{
             result.innerHTML = "Erro: " + xmlreq.statusText;
         }
     }
 };
 xmlreq.send(null);
 }
```

Nesse caso a váriavel "Result" aplica o resultado dentro da div Resultado, mas não nos inputs que defini para serem alimentados....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitua:

```
result.innerHTML = xmlreq.responseText;
```

Por:

```
document.getElementById("iddomeucampo").value = xmlreq.responseText;
```

ficando:

```
function getDados() {

 // Declaração de Variáveis
 var nome   = document.getElementById("txtnome").value;
 var result = document.getElementById("Resultado");
 var xmlreq = CriaRequest();

 // Exibi a imagem de progresso
 result.innerHTML = '<img src="images/Progresso.gif"/>';

 // Iniciar uma requisição
 xmlreq.open("GET", "processa.php?txtnome=" + nome, true);

 // Atribui uma função para ser executada sempre que houver uma mudança de ado
 xmlreq.onreadystatechange = function(){

     // Verifica se foi concluído com sucesso e a conexão fechada (readyState=4)
     if (xmlreq.readyState == 4) {

         // Verifica se o arquivo foi encontrado com sucesso
         if (xmlreq.status == 200) {
             document.getElementById("iddomeucampo").value = xmlreq.responseText;
         }else{
             result.innerHTML = "Erro: " + xmlreq.statusText;
         }
     }
 };
 xmlreq.send(null);
 }
```

Comment: Fiz como você disse amigo, mas entrou na linha: result.innerHTML = '<img src="images/Progresso.gif"/>'; e não saiu mais. Conferi o nome da div e do input e estão corretos. Alguma idéia? Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: document.getElementById("Resultado") existe?

Comment: Mudei a div para "Content" e para e o input é "nomeFunc". Os nomes tanto no ajax.js quanto no php estão iguais....

Comment: Abre o console do navegador e veja o erro

Comment: Criei outra div, com outro nome e mesmo nome de campo. Ai ele deixou o progresso rodando na div nova e ai sim colocou o valor na div que queria. Direi a barra de progresso e inverteu todos valores, apontei para uma div e ele armazenou na outra. Como vejo os erros no console? Obrigado

Comment: Depende do navegador que voce ta usando. Se você postar o código todo facilita

Comment: Amigo, obrigado pela ajuda. Retirei a perfumaria daquela barra de progresso e exatamente com o seu código funcionou. Ficou sem o "pesquisando", mas no momento não tem problema. Novamente, obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Tranquilo. Abraços